# Suma de tabla dinámica se muestra en 0

Tags: php

Un saludos a todos.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Tengo un formulario de consulta que trae información por usuario, hay una columna que muestra el precio del producto comprado por el usuario. Quiero sumar toda la columna donde esta el precio pero el resultado me devuelve 0.

```
 <?php }
       while ($row_consulta = mysql_fetch_array ($consulta));{
       $total= 0;
       $total = $total + $consulta['totald']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
        print_r($total); 
    }
    
       ?>
```

Y el resto del código

```
<?php require_once('Connections/EDD.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_consulta = 20;
$pageNum_consulta = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_consulta'])) {
  $pageNum_consulta = $_GET['pageNum_consulta'];
}
$startRow_consulta = $pageNum_consulta * $maxRows_consulta;

$varusuario_consulta = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['usuario'])) {
  $varusuario_consulta = $_GET['usuario'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_EDD, $EDD);
$query_consulta = sprintf("SELECT usuario, `date`, telefono, producto, cantidad, piso, totald, totalbs, preciop FROM t_pedidos WHERE usuario LIKE %s ORDER BY `date` DESC", GetSQLValueString("%" . $varusuario_consulta . "%", "text"));
$query_limit_consulta = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_consulta, $startRow_consulta, $maxRows_consulta);
$consulta = mysql_query($query_limit_consulta, $EDD) or die(mysql_error());
$row_consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_consulta'])) {
  $totalRows_consulta = $_GET['totalRows_consulta'];
} else {
  $all_consulta = mysql_query($query_consulta);
  $totalRows_consulta = mysql_num_rows($all_consulta);
}
$totalPages_consulta = ceil($totalRows_consulta/$maxRows_consulta)-1;
?><style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-top: 2cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.Estilo2 {font-size: 18px}
-->
</style><form name="form1" method="get" action="dp.php?usuario=usuario">
  <label></label><label></label>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="1105" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bgcolor="#CC99FF">Buscar deuda</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bgcolor="#CC99FF"><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bgcolor="#CC99FF"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Consultar">
      <input name="volver" type="button" id="volver" onClick="location='cp.php'" value="Volver"></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Usuario</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Fecha</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Teléfono</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Producto</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Cantidad</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Piso</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Total en $</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Total en Bs.</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Precio Producto</span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['usuario']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['date']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['telefono']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['producto']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['cantidad']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['piso']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['totald']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['totalbs']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['preciop']; ?></td>
        
      </tr>
```

Edit: modifiqué el código así:

```
<?php }
// Inicializa antes del ciclo. De otra forma, lo vuelves cero en cada iteración...
while ($row_consulta = mysql_fetch_array ($consulta));{
$total= 0;  
 $total = $total + $row_consulta['totald']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
 

print_r($total);
   }
  
      ?>
```

Pero se muestra en 0 al hacer print_r($row_consulta); no se muestra nada, en blanco.

Edit: Gracias por las recomendaciones, mis disculpa si mi mal uso del foro tiende a confundir. Aquí el código inicial. Ya realice las modificaciones indicadas y el resultado sigue siendo 0.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/EDD.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . doubleval($theValue) . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_consulta = 20;
$pageNum_consulta = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_consulta'])) {
  $pageNum_consulta = $_GET['pageNum_consulta'];
}
$startRow_consulta = $pageNum_consulta * $maxRows_consulta;

$varusuario_consulta = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['usuario'])) {
  $varusuario_consulta = $_GET['usuario'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_EDD, $EDD);
$query_consulta = sprintf("SELECT usuario, `date`, telefono, producto, cantidad, piso, totald, totalbs, preciop FROM t_pedidos WHERE usuario LIKE %s ORDER BY `date` DESC", GetSQLValueString("%" . $varusuario_consulta . "%", "text"));
$query_limit_consulta = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_consulta, $startRow_consulta, $maxRows_consulta);
$consulta = mysql_query($query_limit_consulta, $EDD) or die(mysql_error());
$row_consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_consulta'])) {
  $totalRows_consulta = $_GET['totalRows_consulta'];
} else {
  $all_consulta = mysql_query($query_consulta);
  $totalRows_consulta = mysql_num_rows($all_consulta);
}
$totalPages_consulta = ceil($totalRows_consulta/$maxRows_consulta)-1;
?><style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 3cm;
    margin-top: 2cm;
    margin-right: 3cm;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.Estilo2 {font-size: 18px}
-->
</style><form name="form1" method="get" action="dp.php?usuario=usuario">
  <label></label><label></label>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="1105" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bgcolor="#CC99FF">Buscar deuda</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bgcolor="#CC99FF"><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bgcolor="#CC99FF"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Consultar">
      <input name="volver" type="button" id="volver" onClick="location='cp.php'" value="Volver"></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="30" align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Usuario</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Fecha</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Teléfono</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Producto</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Cantidad</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Piso</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Total en $</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Total en Bs.</span></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#CC99FF"><span class="Estilo2">Precio Producto</span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['usuario']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['date']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['telefono']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['producto']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['cantidad']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['piso']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['totald']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['totalbs']; ?></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap bordercolor="#333333" bgcolor="#8BF8F8"><?php echo $row_consulta['preciop']; ?></td>
        
      </tr>
      <?php }
       while ($row_consulta = mysql_fetch_array ($consulta));{
       $total= 0;
       $total = $total + $consulta['totald']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
    }
    echo $total;
       ?>
  </table>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  
</form>
<?php

mysql_free_result($consulta);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando funciones mysql declaradas obsoletas en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminadas en PHP 7.0.0?  Primero me plantearia actualizar eso, y ya se que no tiene que ver con tu pregunta, es para que no pierdas el tiempo con algo obsoleto.

Comment: Por otra parte, me huele que el problema lo tienes aqui: `$total = $total + $consulta['totald'];` pues debería ser `$total = $total + $row_consulta['totald'];` seguramente.

Comment: A ver, estas desvirtuando la pregunta, cambiando su contexto sobre la marcha y eso no ayudará a nadie ni será bueno para que nadie te pueda ayudar mejor... si la editas hazlo bien sin cargarte el contexto que @Alfabravo se habia tomado la molestia de incluir.  Por favor, pon el código completo y cuando lo tengas bien puesto borra esa no-respuesta de antes. Y ponlo en el orden correcto, porque creo que estas ejecutando un mysql_fetch_array y un mysql_fetch_assoc sobre la misma consulta, y dudo que eso sea factible ni optimo para lo que pretendes conseguir.

Comment: Un typo es que al final del `while` NO debe llevar punto y coma `;`

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Así no vas a estar enredado usando el sitio :)

Answer (score 2):

Estás haciendo

```
while ($row_consulta = mysql_fetch_array ($consulta));{
  $total= 0;
  $total = $total + $consulta['totald']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
  print_r($total); 
}
```

El problema es que la fila a usar está en `$row_consulta`. En la variable `$consulta` está toda la metadata y un handler del resultSet con todos los datos. Así pues, ese índice totalld está en la fila, no en el handler.

```
$total= 0;  // Inicializa antes del ciclo. De otra forma, lo vuelves cero en cada iteración...
while ($row_consulta = mysql_fetch_array ($consulta));{
  $total = $total + $row_consulta['totald']; // Sumar variable $total + resultado de la consulta
}
print_r($total);  // revisa el total cuando termines de sumar
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Igual me esta mostrando 0 como resultado

Comment: @Jimrivero Por favor edita tu pregunta y muéstranos cómo lo modificaste (para ver por qué igual muestra cero). Dónde muestra cero, en el print_r??? Te toca pintar el contenido de $row_consulta para ver qué trae esa columna :)

Comment: Efectivamente en el print_r($total); se muestra en 0 al hacer print_r($row_consulta); no se muestra nada, en blanco.